# Batch Clip shapefiles by filename or attribute using Python?

Tags: python, clip, batch

I used a Split Layer By Attribute tool I found online to split a feature class into 90 different shapefiles. These were outputted to a folder with the name for each shapefile ending in a 5 digit unique ID relating to the attribute I split the feature class by. I have done the same thing to another feature class that I need to clip to the first mentioned set of shapefiles, based on the same 5 digit code tied to the end of the shapefile name. How can I batch clip these 90 shapefiles using Python based on the similar file name or similar attribute? Code examples needed because I am new to Python!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Could you please supply an example of the intended input and output? What do the names look like for the first and second datasets?

Comment: Essentially I have a feature class of 90 polygons that overlaps another feature class of 90 counties. The polygons that overlap the county boundaries share a 5 digit ID, which is a unique county ID, to its pertaining county that I'd like to clip too. I've called my 90 polygons to be clipped to their county boundary my base layer. So when I run the Split by Attribute tool it ties the ID to the end. So if the ID was 24033 the file name would look like "Base_24033.shp".

Comment: Please [edit] your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this, but this should get you started:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import os

// Set workspace to location of shapefiles
env.workspace = 'C:/path1'

// Path to second set of shapefiles
path2 = 'C:/path2/'

// Get all shapefiles in one path to get loop value
files = arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp")

// Loop through shapefiles
for f in files:
  // Grab ID value on end of shapefile name
  name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(f))[0]
  id = name[-5:]

  // Concatenate to file name in clip process
  arcpy.Clip_analysis(f, path2 + 'shapefile_name_' + str(id) + '.shp', 'C:/Output_' + str(id) + '.shp', '')
```

Be sure to update the references (File Paths, Environment, and Shapefile Names) correctly.